# How do I set the page title from view result (same as the view result)

Tags: views, 6

I have set up a View that shows a random page from the site filtered according to node types and uses the `Global : Random (asc)` sort criteria. It displays only one result per page and a fresh page is shown every time the page is refreshed.

I want to set the view's page title to be same as the node displayed. I am doing this using javascript right now, but would prefer a PHP alternative that I could either use in the template or the views setting directly.

Setting the page title using javascript isn't SEO friendly.

I am using the latest version of Drupal 6 with the latest stable release of Views 3.

The results of `print_r($view->result, true)` (as requested) are :

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [_random] => 0.00171253550957193
            [radioactivity_node_1_s_energy] => 3
            [node_title] => <Title of the node being displayed>
            [nid] => 393
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside a views template, you could call `drupal_set_title()` with whatever you want out of the `$view->result` array.  You can put a `drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($view->result, true) . '</pre>');` or its equivalent in there to see what you have to work with.

In Style Settings, just click on Theme Information, and choose one, I'd suggest modifying the Style Output one because you could also change `$title` in there as well.

ADDITIONS DUE TO COMMENTS:

No, views will not set this for you, I thought that's what you were asking.

In your views template for the view in question, you need to dig into your row result to get the value you want and then call `drupal_set_title()` with that.  Calling it with a null value only returns the existing title, if any.

For example, if you put the print_r() of your result in there, you will see what values you have to work with, and then you use them with this to set the title.

Let's say you have something like this:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [node_title] => Sirens
        [nid] => 240
        [_random] => 0.000554758124570137
    )
```

which is the view result from a view I just put together that randomly returns node titles, you would do something like this in your template:

```
$title=check_plain($view->result[0]->node_title);
drupal_set_title($title);
```

You could also put this in a pre_render() hook like so:

```
function YOURMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {

  if ($view->name==NAMEOFYOURVIEW) { // && $view->current_display == 'page' if needed
    $title=check_plain($view->result[0]->node_title);
    drupal_set_title($title);
  }

}
```

But either way, since I don't know exactly what your view row looks like, I can't tell you precisely what `$view->result[0]......`  you need.

Also, all of this is assuming your theme behaves nicely with the $head_title variable as well.

Comment: I tried adding `<?php drupal_set_title(t($title)); ?>` and `<?php drupal_set_title($title); ?>` in the style output template, separately in different attempts. None of the approaches worked.

Comment: what did you set `$title` to?

Comment: I did not set it to anything. Isn't that set by the View?

Comment: I did whatever you mentioned here, and it works, except it's still not changing the document title. I thought `drupal_set_title()` does the same. Can the `pre_render()` hook be added to my theme's template.php?

Comment: I've only used the pre_render() hook within a module, and a quick test here didn't work by naming it MYTHEME_views_pre_render() and putting it in my template.php file, so if you don't have a custom module, putting the code in your views template looks to be the only way to go.  I would put a `$title='foobarbaz'; set_drupal_title($title);` or something in there to make sure your template is being called as all of the above worked here.  Also, if you want to edit your question with a print_r() of your `$view->result`, that would help out as well.

Comment: Yeah, I tried adding it to my template.php file too, didn't work. I have added the result of the `print_r()` you requested in my question, take a look. It's not much different from yours, except I have also used the radioactivity module to help sort the results obtained from the view in a descending order. Please remember that only one node is displayed per page.

Comment: Also, could you tell me what do you mean by `Also, all of this is assuming your theme behaves nicely with the $head_title variable as well.`

Comment: This is a case of "it should work" as you have your title is in there similarly.  So, you have to make sure that your view template is correct, it should be named something like `views-view-unformatted--VIEWNAME.tpl.php` (assuming unformatted is your row style, insert whatever here if otherwise) and that Views is seeing it...

Comment: $head_title is the variable that is put inside `<title> ... </title>` in the page `<head>` by most themes.

Comment: I have a custom theme (Zen subtheme, actually) that does have `$head_title` in the title tag.
The template filename is also correct, I copy-pasted it form the theming infomation field and then using the rescan template files button. The filename appears in bold over there, so I assume it's correct and the view sees it.

Comment: The node title is getting set, but the document/page title isn't.